# Can you substitute white wine with rose?

Tags: sauce, steak, wine, mustard

My recipe calls for white wine, but I only have rose. my rose is dry.

Will this work? It's paired with mustard and tarragon for a steak

Answer (score 2):

If the rose is dry this should work. The combination of flavours you've listed should go well with a dry wine